# What property of these sets contradicts the fact that f is a function

Tags: combinatorics, functions, inverse-function

Assume that $X=\{a,b\}\\$

There must be a contradiction in the following statements: I.e. there is something lurking here which tells us that this is not a function.

1. $\#\{x:f^{1}(x)=a\}=1\\$
2. $\#\{x:f^{2}(x)=a\}=2\\$
3. $\#\{x:f^{1}(x)=b\}=1\\$
4. $\#\{x:f^{2}(x)=b\}=0\\$

***What I Know*: we can show this combinatorially** 

I know the information encoded as a matrix (of rows) of preimages with entries $S_{ij}=\#f^{-j}(x_i)$ is given by $S=[[1,2],[1,0]]$. For example, letting $x_{1}=a$ and $x_{2}=b$ and  the number of elements which under two applications of $f$ yield the first domain element, $x_{1}=a$ , is given by $S_{(1,2)}=2$

Reverse engineering this gives two possible forward "image" matrices (of rows) with entries $F_{ij}=f^{j}(x_i)$ one $a$ and one $b$ in column 1 and two $a$'s in column 2. 


Thus the options are either 

$F_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
f(a)=a & f(f(a))=a \\
f(b)=b & f(f(b))=a \\
\end{array}\right)$

or

$F_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
f(a)=b & f(f(a))=a \\
f(b)=a & f(f(b))=a \\
\end{array}\right)$ 

Both of which contradict f is functional as  $F_{1}$ implies $f(b)=b$ and $f(b)=a$ by row 2, since the entries correspond to $F_{ij}=f^{j}(x_i)$. Likewise in $F_{2}$ it is implied that implies $f(a)=b$ by entry (1,1) and $f(b)=a$ by entry (1,2). 

So combinatorially we can see the problem, but I'd like to be able to show the issue from the mere list of set size specifications at the top of the post.

Comment: What is $f^{-2}$?

Comment: Second iterated inverse: $f^{-j}(x)$ is the set of elements which under j applications of f gives x

Comment: Is $f$ understood to be a relation on $X$, i.e., a subset of $X\times X$?

Comment: You defined what $X$ is. But what is $f$? It's impossible to address a question if we don't know what the question is about.

Comment: $f$ is some endomorphism from/to $X$ satisfying the four preimage set size conditions. Based on this, the only options for the values of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are given by column 1 of the two forward matrices: contradicting functionality by a combinatorial argument. I'm trying however to find a contradiction in $f$ being functional from just the four properties

Comment: Your four conditions are mutually inconsistent: the first and third imply that $f$ is a function on $X$, while the second implies that it is not a function.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Suppose $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=a$ then $f(f(a))=a$ and $f(f(b))=f(a)=a$ thus the second condition is not, of itself, problematic.

Comment: @Bradford: But that isn’t what the second condition says: it says that $f(f(a))$ is two different elements, not that there are two distinct elements $x$ and $y$ such that $f(f(x))=a=f(f(y))$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Woah! Major mistake on my part, I'm not sure why I was using the negative. I want to define the inverse sets as the sets which under FORWARD application reach a particular element. I think I've been inside too long.

Answer (score 1):

If $\ f\ $ were a function from $\ X\ $ to $\ X\ $  satisfying conditions $3$ and $4$, then condition $4$ tells us that $\ f(b)=a\ $, since $\ f(b)=$$b\implies$$ f^2(b)=b\implies$$\#\{x: f^2(x)=b\}\ge1\ $. Condition $3$ then tells us that $\ f(a)=b\ $, because we would otherwise have $\ \#\{x: f(x)=b\}=0\ $. Thus, for $3$ and $4$ to be satisfied, we must have $\ f(a)=b\ $ and $\ f(b)=a\ $.  But this function does not satisfy $4$, because, once again, $\ f^2(b)=b\ $.

Thus, there is no function from $\ X\ $ to $\ X\ $ which can satisfy both conditions $3$ and $4$, let alone all four of the conditions.